# How to redirect println output from console to specified log file in grails using log4j (Config.groovy)

Tags: grails, logging, console, log4j, stdout

In my application I use `println "Some text here ${var}"` statements to send some "debug" info to the console. But I want to send data to the specified file.

Could it be done via configuration of Config.groovy file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Log messages have to go through log4j for them to be handled by Grails and log4j.

What you could do is replace all instances of `println` in your code with `log.debug`; that should be a simple search and replace with your text editor or IDE.

If that isn't possible you could try to replace the global `System.out` object with a File-backed `PrintStream` object in `BootStrap.groovy`.

Comment: Ok. Now I see... Thank you for an extended answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use logger directly. It's easy, clean, documented and flexible.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#logging

Comment: As what I do for now... But question is still open )